# How to remove duplicate entries from a file?

Tags: sort

I have a comma-separated list of domain-names in a file; unfortunately there are duplicate entries for some domain-names.

Is there a way to find and remove the duplicate entries from the file?

The sample output is as below:-

```
culturaurbanashop.com,remaxcorn.info,enjoygoing.com,full-kit-wankers.co.uk,paracaballo.com,radiopozarica.com,sprinklermaps.com,unlock-any-phone.com,voipbillingplus.com,yedincicadde.net,klasseaparte.com,allfortheweb.com,indulgesolutions.com,fastextcafe.info,titi.sickworldhosting.com,kebeico.com,facemowi.it,mellat.info,sal-gov.info,hindustan4848.com,nawaopls.co.za,familie-ries.de
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
tr ',' '\n' < infile | sort -u | paste -sd, -
```

Answer (score 1):

If you mean that duplicates should be removed from comma separated lists of words (where words are sequences of non-blanks), then maybe something like:

```
$ echo 2,1,1,2,c,1 a,a,a,b,c | perl -M'List::MoreUtils uniq' -lpe '
    s/[\S,]+,[\S,]+/join ",", uniq(split",",$&)/ge'
2,1,c a,b,c
```